# Call Event Explicitly

Tags: c#, events

Is that possible somehow to trigger an event which belongs another class in C#, such:

```
class foo
{ 
   public delegate void myEvntHandler();
   public event myEvntHandler onTesting;

   .
   .
   .
}

    class Main
    {
       public static void Main()
       {
         foo obj = new foo();

         ...

         obj.onTesting.Invoke();
       }
    }
```

on this sample I mean:  **obj.onTesting.Invoke();**

Comment: You will get  **The event  can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= ** error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't invoke it directly from another class. That's the point of events (Encapsulation).

You need a helper method

```
class foo
{ 
   public delegate void myEvntHandler();
   public event myEvntHandler onTesting;

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        if(onTesting !=null)
            onTesting ();
    }
}
```

Then call `RaiseEvent` method instead

```
class Main
{
   public static void Main()
   {
     foo obj = new foo();

     ...

     obj.RaiseEvent();
   }
}
```

If you need to invoke it the way you did, just remove the `event` keyword and use a delegate. Which doesn't prevent you form doing so.(I don't recommend it)

Comment: Of course this defeats the entire purpose of using an event in the first place.

Comment: @Servy If `RaiseEvent` method does nothing other than raising event I agree with you. If it does some side effects and raises the event it doesn't defeat the purpose IMO.

Comment: Sure, the whole point is that when *doing something else* the event is triggered.  You don't just fire the event alone, you perform some action and the event is fired when that action happens.  Just about every event ever is fired as a result of some member being invoked, the point is that it's not *just* doing that.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The whole purpose of events is to wrap a delegate while explicitly prohibiting all access to it other than adding/removing an event handler.  The `event` keyword is there specifically to prevent any class other than the class that declares the event from invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: under the hood there no such thing as an "event" unlike delegates which are real objects. event is just a convenience for two methods (to add and remove handlers) and a **private** **hidden** field of type myEvntHandler.

Logically it makes no sense to raise an event from outside the class: The whole point of an event is that it is raised by the class when the class detects some trigger.

If you just want it to raise an event in order to test another class that has added a handler then the correct way to go is to:

1. move the event to an interface
2. implement the interface in your real class
3. create a test class that also implements the interface and add your "RaiseEvent" method to that.
4. Inject the interface into your unit under test